# Gravity Forms Required Field

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I created catering order form in gravity forms for WordPress, I have Food Items, Enter Quantity and Select Trey Size fields. Now while filing form by visitors, if they choose any dropdown options, they must Enter Quantity (i want to make it required) only if they choose any dropdown options from Select Trey Size.
Form image- https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPpuc.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question? Please ask a concise, understandable question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created catering order form in gravity forms for WordPress, I have Food Items, Enter Quantity and Select Trey Size fields. Now while filing form by visitors, if they choose any dropdown options, they must Enter Quantity (i want to make it required) only if they choose any dropdown options from Select Trey Size. Form image- https://imgur.com/a/RcDTdqA

Answer (score 0):

You can check "required" under the general tab of the number field.  You can then use the conditional logic feature to say "show" if dropdown field does not equal "select tray size".

Comment: It won't make the field required on change. It will make required by default. 
To make it required you will have write javascript code on change event.

Comment: True but using JS seems like overkill...the quantity field only needs to show if an item is chosen.  The number field's default can be set to '0' to make sure the form submits while the field is required and hidden.